# mongod won't start after upgrade from 3 to 5

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm running ubuntu 20.04 and did the following:

```
$ sudo apt purge '*mongo*
```

and

```
$ sudo apt install -y mongodb-org
```

everything appeared to install correclty but when I run `$ sudo systemctl status mongod` I get a failure

The log shows the following errors:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-28T04:58:05.912-07:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-28T04:58:05.912-07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":1019}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-28T04:58:05.912-07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

How do I fix?

Comment: Did you stop MongoDB before uninstall it?

Comment: yes. I think you can't upgrade from 3 to 5, its not even really an upgrade, but rather removing and installing

Comment: delete /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock, restart the service

Comment: didn't help. i had to delete 3.x db and install 5.0.9

Comment: didn't help with ""Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}" error or the WiredTiger  compatibility error from the other question?

Comment: noope. didn't help.

Comment: I had to delete all data `rm -rf /var/lib/mongod/*`